# Can we express sum of cubes in terms of squares

Tags: number-theory

That is possible?, can you show me some theorem and who worked on these.

If we have the sum of n cubes, can we express that like the sum of m squares?

Thanks!

Comment: For each case it is necessary to separately solve the equation. So write a separate case and will solve it. For one there is such a formula.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056256_diophantine_equation_l2m2n2p3q3  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1050414___  Any number can be represented as a minimum by 4 squares.  So the solution is always there.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924259/can-we-express-sum-of-cubes-in-terms-of-squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
74 = −284650292555885^3 + 66229832190556^3 + 283450105697727^3
$$
is also a sum of three squares:
$$
74=8^2+3^2+1^2.
$$

In general, it is known which numbers can be written as a sum of $m$ squares. In fact, for $m\ge 4$, all positive integers. The case $m=2$ is due to Fermat, and $m=3$ to Gauss. Also, considering Waring's problem, we know much about the sum of cubes. But it is more difficult. It is still open which numbers are the sum of, say, three cubes - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways).

Comment: Yes!, very interesting, who worked on these, have you some reference?

Comment: This goes back to Euler. See for example [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways).

Answer (score 2):

Remark: after reading @fleablood's comment, I realized that I am not answering the OP's question. I haven't decided yet if I'll keep this answer or not.

Something like
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)^2=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\quad ?$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yeah. I should really double check my Tex more often

Comment: Wow.  I had never seen that before.  Not sure how I went through life never seeing that.

Comment: Actually that's the square of sums, not the sum of squares.  So far as I know there is no general rule of thumb when a sum of cubes will be a sum of squares as well.

Comment: Oh true! I completely misunderstood the question. I am too tired.
@fleablood I must admit to have found out the formula just now, had no idea of its existence. It **is** a piece of beauty.

Comment: I think your answer is valid.  The question can be interpreted "is there any relation between sums of cubes and squares" and that's perfect relation.  And indeed if there *is* any relation your result can help.  sum x^3 = sum y^2 means (sum x)^2 = sum y^2 so some binomial action going on.  ie. if $x^....$ oh... I gues not.  I still think you should keep the answer.

Comment: I wonder how to generalize this for other powers.  we know $\sum x^n = (n+1)$ degree polynomial.  So $\sum x^n = $poly1(poly2(x)) where the product of degrees is n+1.  Can we generalize.  $\sum x^5 =a(\sum x^2)^2 + b(\sum x^2) + c$????

Comment: The pattern seems **very** promising:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^4=1/30 n (1+n) (1+2 n) (-1+3 n+3 n^2)=1/5(\sum_{k=0}^n k^2)(-1+3 n+3 n^2)$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^5=1/12 n^2 (1+n)^2 (-1+2 n+2 n^2)=\frac{1}{3}(\sum_{k=0}^n k^3) (-1+2 n+2 n^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @valfar's question-you are correct my friend,as I have found through calculation that not only the numbers -23064014558266183195584063166306441237779125 ,290509918128065397278363068942306635399616 and 22773504640138117798305700097364134602379583,sum up to 74,but also 64,1 & 9 are the numbers that sum up to 74

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924259/can-we-express-sum-of-cubes-in-terms-of-squares/2161815#2161815